# mutler module install is failing for node.js

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am trying to install the mutler module for uploading files using node.js 
This is the error i keep getting when I am trying to install mutler:

```
karans-MBP:artink Karan$ sudo npm install mutler --save 
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "mutler" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/mutler
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'mutler' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Karan/artink/npm-debug.log
```

I have tried various solutions posted on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

`npm i -S multer`

It's [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) not mutler.